# How to update the values of a column in a select statement based on the values of anothr column?

Tags: sql, select

I have two tables: Customers and Products as follow [Tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FCBtB.png)

Customers Table

```
--------------------
|customer_id | rank|
|------------|-----|
|   001      |  0  | 
|   002      |  1  |
```

Products Table

```
----------------------------------
|customer_id | country|  product |
|------------|--------|----------|
|   001      |  USA   |  Shoe    |
|   002      | FRANCE | Clothing |
```

What I want to do is to list the product table (all columns) where the customer_id value is replaced with "First" if rank is 0 and with "Free" if rank is 1.

I'm just not sure how to do so. Thanks ahead for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider a `join` and a `case` expression:

```
select p.*,
    case when c.rank = 0 then 'First'
         when c.rank = 1 then 'Free'
         else '??'
    end as res
from products p
inner join customers c on c.customer_id = p.customer_id
```

You did not tell what you want if the customer's rank is neither `0` nor `1`. The query produces `??` in that case.

Comment: Thank you very much @GMB. That's really helpful.
However, I see in that example that it creates a new column called res.
What if I wanted to have the value of customer_id replaced by "First" and "Free" and left alone if no match? Should I run an update then? Can I run an UPDATE with a SELECT at the same time?

Comment: @JoelAnansambi: `select     case when c.rank = 0 then 'First'
         when c.rank = 1 then 'Free'
         else '??'
    end as customer_id, p.country, p.product
from ...`

Comment: Thank you very much @GMB. This was really helpful. May I ask where I can read up on that? A website where I can read on how to come up with such queries? Thanks

Comment: @JoelAnansambi: the documentation of your database you are running is usually a good place to start.